# Meteor deployment fibers issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I deploy a Meteor v1.6.1 app on Ubuntu 17.10.

**MongoDB**: mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.6.3
**NodeJS**: node-v8.10.0-x64

This is the build error:
[image: This is the build error]
How can I fix this?

Comment: It does not seem to do anything with deployment, as it seems to be an error from running the app on MS-Windows and ls related to a schema mismatch in `simpl-schema`. Do you know Meteor development? Is there relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with your schema. You have declared that the `readConfirmed` key of your document is an Array, but you have failed to declare what it is an array of.

For example, if `readConfirmed` is an array of strings, you would use the following code in your schema:

```
readConfirmed: {
    type: Array,
    label: 'Array of IDs of users who have read and confirmed',
},
'readConfirmed.$': {
    type: String,
    label: 'Each ID in readConfirmed array',
},
```

The first object tells `simpl-schema` that the `readConfirmed` key is an array. The second line uses the `$` to tell `simple-schema` that each individual item in the array is a string.

This example works if each item is a string, but what if each item is an object? All you need to do then is add another layer where you explain what each key in the object is:

```
readConfirmed: {
    type: Array,
    label: 'Array of IDs of users who have read and confirmed',
},
'readConfirmed.$': {
    type: Object,
    label: 'Data about each user who has read and confirmed',
},
'readConfirmed.$._id': {
    type: String,
    label: 'ID of each user who has read and confirmed',
},
'readConfirmed.$.name': {
    type: String,
    label: 'Name of each user who has read and confirmed',
},
```